# Calling class function first time gave correct answer but second time gave completely wrong answer

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

I am using a function that calculates the haversine distance between 2 GPS coordinates. I took the code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/haversine-formula-to-find-distance-between-two-points-on-a-sphere/. I changed it slightly to fit my needs:

```
double Localization::haversine(double* first){
    double currLat { first[0] }, currLong { first[1] };
    double dLat { (home[0] - currLat) * M_PI / 180.0 };
    double dLon { (home[1] - currLong) * M_PI / 180.0 };

    currLat = (currLat) * M_PI / 180.0;
    home[0] = (home[0]) * M_PI / 180.0;

    double a { std::pow(std::sin(dLat / 2), 2) +
               std::pow(std::sin(dLon / 2), 2) *
               std::cos(currLat) * std::cos(home[0])
             };
    
    double rad { 6371e3 }; // Meters
    double c { 2 * std::asin(std::sqrt(a)) };

    return rad * c;
}
```

The data for the pointer `home`:

```
Latitude: 47.3977419,
Longitude: 8.5455935,
```

The data for pointer `first` (same as `coordinates[population[1][0]]`):

```
Latitude: 47.39390837,
Longitude: 8.55069968,
```

I pass in the `first` variable using the following function:

```
double* Localization::cost(){
    double* data = new double[size];
    for(int i{}; i < size; ++i){
        
        // I am essentially passing in the same data over and over
        data[i] = haversine(coordinates[population[1][0]]);   
    } 
    return data;
}
```

When I print out everything using:
**This is called first thing in the constructor method**

```
double* data { cost() };
    for(int i{}; i < size; ++i){
        printf("%f", data[i]);
    }
```

I get the correct answer once, but every answer after is completely wrong:

```
[ INFO] [1631240237.529621569]: 573.958798         // Correct Answer
[ INFO] [1631240237.530186401]: 5177976.557157
[ INFO] [1631240237.530198475]: 5268356.735750
[ INFO] [1631240237.530204293]: 5269934.167445
[ INFO] [1631240237.530209432]: 5269961.698822
[ INFO] [1631240237.530214666]: 5269962.179335
[ INFO] [1631240237.530219592]: 5269962.187722
```

My first thought was that there was a potential overflow within the program, but I tried to return a long double from the haversine and print it out, and the same issue (probably the wrong way to figure that out anyway). I realized that once I ran the `haversine` function once, the next answer will always be some sort of large incorrect number. So this gave me the thought that the variables defined within the function are just not resetting, after each call, thus giving me unusually weird answers after getting the correct one. Even this is still a bit skeptical, so I am completely unsure what could possibly be causing this issue.

Comment: Can you edit your question and replace all the isolated code snippets with a single, complete, [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown*** into an empty file then compile, run, and reproduce your problem? Otherwise, can you explain what exactly leads you to believe that the problem must be in the shown code, and not in the code that's not shown? After all, if a function gives wrong results that doesn't necessarily mean that there's something wrong with its logic. Something could be wrong with all the data the function uses, and this one uses data that's not shown.

Comment: We don't know the content of home array, but this looks suspicious : home[0] = (home[0]) * M_PI / 180.0; since you keep using home[0] to calculate a over and over again.

Comment: @PKramer You are absolutely right. I completely missed that line of code. When i fixed that line, the program worked as expected. Thanks.